# How to run the same tool in multi-user system 2008

Tags: windows, tcp

everyone!
I meet some problems and I hope some one can give some help.I wirte a tool,the tool recvice all tcp request and forward the dest server and show the client ip.Now I have a server windows 2008 and have three accounts, I run it in every account and I hope the tool will show the same client ip information,however,Just one account show the ip,and others account show nothing.I don't konw why and how to reslove it.
I poor in English,So I dram a picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtyyO.jpg)

Comment: Try listening on different port for each user session...

Comment: I want to the tool show the same message of client in different accounts.I don't konw the mechanism of windows multi-user system.